# Человек - люди, ребенок - дети

Tags: словообразование

Как известно, в большинстве своем множественное число образуется так: собака - собаки, лошадь - лошади, кит - киты. Это что касается живых существ. И только человек выпадает из этой схемы, потому что у него множественное число обозначается совершенно другим словом: человек - люди, ребенок - дети.
Почему такая ситуация возникла именно в отношении человека?
Извините, если вопрос глупый.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Почему такая ситуация возникла именно в отношении человека?

Ну если одной фразой - и точно по вопросу, то потому, что это самое актуальное. Вы не замечали, что все неправильности в языке всегда проявляются в отношении наиболее употребительных и самых нужных вещей? Это свойство языка.

А вот как это произошло...

С "детями" все понятно. Дитя относилось только к младенцам, для обозначения собственно отношения "потомок" потребовалось что-то иное.

С "людьми" сложнее. исходным, понятно, в обоих числах были формы, образованные от корня "люд". Однако со временем людьми (причем преимущественно во множественном числе) стали называться зависимые, дворовые и прочие низко стоящие слои. Потребовалось противопоставление их гордо звучащему человеку-мужу. Так "человек" стал "человеком" - особью вида хомо сапиенс. Во множественном числе это слово почти не использовалось. 
Но со временем и новое значение слово "люди" (челядь) стало не столь актуальным. И стало обозначать только множественное для человека.

Что ту еще скажешь? Бывает...)))

Comment: У Виноградова написано, что слугу называли "человеком": http://etymolog.ruslang.ru/vinogradov.php?id=tschelovek&vol=2

Comment: Да это и без Виноградова известно.
Что с того?

Comment:  То, что "человек" и есть "дворовый", то есть представитель низко стоящего слоя, так что противопоставление их кажется несколько сомнительным.

Comment: Если вы про противопоставление, то - нет. Виноградов ничего такого не говорит, а вы совершенно "проглотили" исторический аспект. "Человек -  дворовый" стало возможным когда "человек" *уже стало* единственным числом к "люди". А мы тут рассматривали сам этот процесс, т.е. гораздо более раннее явление. 
И потом это только одно из не самых ходовых значений.

Comment: >>"человек" уже стало единственным числом к "люди"

Да, здесь согласен.

Answer (score 3):

Так было не всегда. Были и "человеки", и "людины", до сих пор есть "дитя" и "ребята". Супплетивная схема образования мн. числа появилась, скорее всего, из-за того, что "родные" формы приобрели несколько иной оттенок значения.